# How can I display the data stored by summernote on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, tags, laravel-5.3, summernote

I implement summernote (https://github.com/summernote/summernote) on the laravel 5.3

If I input data then save, on table seems like this :

```
<p>1. chelsea</p><p>2. mu</p><p>3. city</p><p>4. liverpool</p><p>5. arsenal</p>
```

How can I display it without tag p?

So when it displayed will seems like this :

```
1. chelsea
2. mu
3. city
4. liverpool
5. arsenal
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First edit the text accordingly to your desired format inside `summernote` text editor, and save it.

Then you can use this blade syntax to show the text formated:

```
{!! message !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to show:

`<?php echo $variable or html code ; ?>`

because in PHP, echo is used to interpret html code.

Comment: `echo` is not a function it's a language construct. And it doesn't do any parsing. Also mixing regular PHP into Laravel templates, just isn't a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "<p>1. chelsea</p><p>2. mu</p><p>3. city</p><p>4. liverpool</p><p>5. arsenal</p>";
echo strip_tags($text);
```

Use strip_tags php method to convert html to string.
[Refernce link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($GuideCont  as $item )

    <input type="text" value="{{$item->id}}" hidden>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header border-bottom border-info">
            
             <h3 class="card-title">{{$item->title }}</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            {!!$item->description !!}    {{--// SummerNote Data --}}
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).